# Вырезать пробелы и невидимые знаки

Tags: php

Суть задачи: подсчитать кол-во символов без пробелов и невидимых знаков. На js делаю вот так:

```
count_char.value = count_char_textarea.value.replace(/ *\n*\r*\t*/g, "").length;
$("#count_char").html(count_char.value);//отображаем кол-во символов
```

А вот на php что-то не соображу как правильно сделать.

```
$counttext = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", " "), '', strip_tags($_POST['text'])); 
$counttext = mb_strlen($counttext,'utf-8');
```

Выводятся разные значения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать регулярные выражения не только в JS но и в PHP. Например так:

```
$filtered_text = preg_replace("/\s+/", '', strip_tags($_POST['text'])); 
$chars_count = mb_strlen($filtered_text,'utf-8');
```

**Замечание:**

Пробельные символы не ограничиваются символами `\r`, `\n` и их комбинацией. В эту группу так же входят символы "" (пробел), `\t`, `\v` и еще несколько других. Поэтому, при использовании регулярных выражений, правильнее применять символьный класс `\s`, который как раз и описывает все пробельные символы. То же самое справедливо и для вашего JavaScript кода.

Comment: Спасибо за столь быстрый ответ.

Comment: Те, кто минусуют, вы хотя бы комментируйте, что не так

Comment: Им проще ткнуть кнопку, чем написать комментарий.